# How to know current textBox and move to next textBox by button click

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my Calculator for solve quadratic equation. First, I enter text to box A and after that I want to move box B (by click "**=**" button).

[[image]

How to know the current textBox and use **if...else** structure to control it?

*Thanks a lot for your answer!*

Comment: Since you probaly use events to determine the input (TextChanged, KeyDown etc.), the `sender` parameter is the Control that triggered the event. You can just cast sender to `TextBox` (or Control) and read the text (e.g., `string textEntered = (sender as Control).Text`). Use the same event handler for all those TextBoxes.

Answer (score 1):

On WinForms: `Form.ActiveControl` is the current control.

It is a property with read and write accessors.

Read to know it.

Write to change it.

So you can do such thing on the click event of a button:

```
if ( this.ActiveControl == textBoxA )
  this.ActiveControl = textBoxB;
else
  // ...
```